# Set font color based on input value

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, display

Doing a fun project for my school club and want to spice up my presentation a little bit. I know what I want but no idea how to make it happen.

I want a line that reads: "Your success rate for energy consumption is (value)%."

I already have the source for the value but I need help with the display.

What I am looking to do is have the font color for the (value) be dynamic based on the value itself. So, if the value is <0 font color=red, if value is =0, font color is yellow, if value is >0 font color is green.

Not being a web designer/code guru I'm not sure how to make this happen in HTML. I also read through a few similar types of questions but the school won't let me upload any JavaScript files but I think I can link to the ajax.googleapis.com site just fine if it's determined I need to use JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To quickly change the font color in html: `String color = "red"; String msg = "<html>Your success rate for energy consumption is <font color=" + color + ">" + value + "</font>%.</html>"`. You can display this string in a JLabel or whatever. Where do you want to display this sort of string?

Comment: Do you want the program to be a web-based application, or would you prefer the program to be more desktop-based (where an IDE or Java compiler such as Eclipse runs the program)?

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java...but you mentioned you want this in html, so most likely you want to use Javascript, not Java. The website you provided is a list of hosted libraries, which you don't need to use for this simple purpose. Unless you find out what format you are creating, it's difficult for others to help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function color() {
   var colorr = document.getElementById("color1").value;
   if(colorr==''){
    document.getElementById("changecolor").style.color = "black";
   }
   else if(colorr<0){
    document.getElementById("changecolor").style.color = "red";
   }
   else if(colorr>0){
    document.getElementById("changecolor").style.color = "green";
   }
   else if(colorr==0){
      document.getElementById("changecolor").style.color = "yellow";
   }
   
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  onkeyup="color();" name="color" id="color1">
<h1 id="changecolor">Change Color on input color</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply and it works perfect in our html application but it isn't working in our report program. I asked the computer teacher and he said to mention it is in a html container in micro strategy. Does that make a difference in the HTML code or javascript? I copied what you provided and added <script></script> to contain the javascript. Not sure if that was the right thing to do. I'm sorry for being so difficult.